# setting a value for a column based on groupby of other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

trying to use pandas `loc` to subset a dataframe by critera and give a value to another column.

#### initialize dataframe

```
import random
random.seed(100)

nums = 100
df = pd.DataFrame({'value':[random.randint(-7, 10) for x in range(nums)],
                      'id': [random.randint(500, 520) for x in range(nums)], 
                     'prod': [random.choice(['carrots', 'apples', 'pears', 'corn', 'baby corn', 'peppers', 'jalapenos', 'chicken', 'beef', 'raddishes']) for x in range(nums)],
                     'region':[random.choice(['east', 'west', 'central', 'south']) for x in range(nums)],
                     'country':[random.choice(['us', 'ca', 'mx']) for x in range(nums)],
                     'tag': np.nan})
```

I'm trying to do something like "filter dataset by `us` or `ca` but only in regions `east` and `west`, and where the sum of value within grouped `prod` and `id` is negative.

doing the following indexes the dataframe by what I just grouped it by, but I'm trying to isolate it by index.

```
df.groupby(['id', 'prod'])['value'].sum().loc[lambda x: x <0].head(10)

id   prod     
500  apples      -6
     carrots     -6
     corn        -6
501  apples      -3
     chicken     -2
502  beef        -3
     pears       -2
503  chicken     -3
504  jalapenos   -4
505  chicken     -4
```

I was trying to do something like:

```
df.loc[(df.country.isin(['us', 'ca'])) & (df.region.isin(['east', 'west'])) & (df.groupby(['id', 'prod'])['value'].sum().loc[lambda x: x <0]), 'tag'] = True
```

how do I use the result from the groupedby dataframe as a filter in a pandas `loc`?

Comment: Unfortunately I can only give you one upvote for the nice setup. It really helps having a data-set to look at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you instead of `.sum()` use `.transform('sum')` you get the grouped result returned per row instead. And by comparing that value with `< 0` you get a boolean mask.

We can then create your different masks on separate rows and join them with `&`.

```
m1 = df.country.isin({'us', 'ca'})
m2 = df.region.isin({'east', 'west'})
m3 = df.groupby(['id', 'prod'])['value'].transform('sum') < 0

df.loc[m1&m2&m3, 'tag'] = True
```

Does this help you?

Comment: thats perfect thank you! I wasn't aware that transform gave back indexes.

Comment: @MattW. If you mean the values you are right. But it is when we compare with `< 0` we get a boolean mask of `True` and `False` that we can combine with the other masks. Glad I could help!